# PostgreSQL json array intersection query

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I have a table with a jsonb **data** column, which looks like this:

```
data: {
    "categories": [
        "Category A",
        "Category D"
    ],
    "something": "dsa",
}
```

I would like to query rows that have one or more strings existing inside **categories** array (not empty intersection).

Let's suppose these strings to check against are "Category A" and "Category B".

How would such query look like?

Here's a query that does similar thing except it checks for all supplied strings to be existing in **categories** array:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE data->'categories' @> '["Category A", "Category B"]'
```

I need this query to match at least one string, not all.

Comment: Which version of PG? There are major differences for json types between 9.3 and 9.4.

Answer (score 14):

There is a [`?|` operator](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSONB-OP-TABLE) taking `jsonb` and `text[]` described as `exists any`:

```
select '["Category A", "Category D"]'::jsonb ?| array['Category A', 'Category B'];
 ?column? 
----------
 t

select '["Category A", "Category D"]'::jsonb ?| array['Category Ax', 'Category B'];
 ?column? 
----------
 f
```

Comment: defo saved my hours! thanks!