# Check if Postgres json array intersects with another array

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy

Is there a postgres jsonb operator that checks whether any one element of a set of elements is in another set of elements?

for example:

```
if ['a', 'b', 'c'] in ['c', 'd', 'e'] = True because c in 2nd set
if ['f', 'g', 'h'] in ['g', 'h', 'i'] = True because of g and h in 2nd set
```

Comment: This would be very easy with a native Postgres array.

Comment: Prolly answered by https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32812526/postgresql-json-array-intersection-query and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39480816/postgres-jsonb-array-query-for-non-empty-intersection

Comment: @IljaEverilä I guess the other questions you point to expect one of the sides to be a PostgreSQL array already. It's not clear from the pseudo-code in this question if both arrays come in `jsonb` type, or if one of them already is provided as `text[]`. (I was assuming the former.)

Comment: I've defined the column as type JSON

Comment: @el_pup_le, just to clarify, both column**s**?

Comment: @Bruno You guessed correctly. On the other hand this question is so vague that should've voted "unclear" instead of dupe.

Comment: just one column, I'm specifying the array of strings. I couldn't get it working with where table_a.post_types::json <@ array['foo']

Comment: I should of included in the question that it is for a join condition

Comment: i think its better to use mongodb for this anyway

Comment: If you are specifying the other side as an array, then this is indeed a duplicate of the question linked to by @IljaEverilä. (Unclear why it being part of a join condition would make a difference, or why MongoDB would be better here, up to you.)

Answer (score 2):

You can expand the JSON array using [`jsonb_array_elements` (when using `jsonb`) or `json_array_elements` (when using `json`)](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html), or directly to text using `jsonb_array_elements_text` (when using `jsonb`) or `json_array_elements_text` (when using `json`), and then turn them into a PostgreSQL array using [`array_agg`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-aggregate.html).

```
WITH json_data(x, y) AS (
    VALUES ('["a", "b", "c"]'::jsonb, '["c", "d", "e"]'::jsonb),
           ('["a", "b", "c"]'::jsonb, '["g", "h", "i"]'::jsonb)
)
, array_data AS (
    SELECT x, (SELECT array_agg(e) AS arr FROM jsonb_array_elements_text(x) e) AS xarr,
           y, (SELECT array_agg(e) AS arr FROM jsonb_array_elements_text(y) e) AS yarr
    FROM json_data
)
SELECT x, y, xarr, yarr, xarr && yarr AS with_intersection FROM array_data
```

This produced these results:

```
        x        |        y        |  xarr   |  yarr   | with_intersection
-----------------+-----------------+---------+---------+-------------------
 ["a", "b", "c"] | ["c", "d", "e"] | {a,b,c} | {c,d,e} | t
 ["a", "b", "c"] | ["g", "h", "i"] | {a,b,c} | {g,h,i} | f
(2 rows)
```